# What does Array.Clear actually do under the covers?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, clr, cil

I'm looking for a answer to what the `Array.Clear(...)` method does under the covers in C#.

I've looked at the IL, but that isn't really yielding any clues, since it simply calls the `System.Array::Clear(...)` method in mscorlib, which then calls an unmanaged portion of the CLR that I can't observe.

The reason why I am asking this, is that I am occasionally getting an SEHException thrown by my call to Array.Clear, and I can't seem to figure out why it is happening.

Unfortunately, Microsoft seems to be a little tight-lipped about what it might mean when the exception is thrown...

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception(v=VS.100).aspx

> Any SEH exception that is not automatically mapped to a specific exception is mapped to the SEHException class by default. For more information, search on "unmanaged exceptions" and "Structured Exception Handling" in the MSDN Library.

Comment: What do you have an Array of that you're trying to Clear?  Why type of objects?

Comment: Post the smallest amount of code that reproduces the error.

Comment: You could always decompile the method with the (formerly free) .NET Reflector.  That will tell you exactly what's going on.

Comment: Something is seriously wrong. Are you using interop or unsafe code?  Can you reproduce the issue in a standalone example?

Comment: I am trying to clear a byte array of 4096 bytes.  The problem comes in the fact that the error only crops up occasionally, and never in a test app.  I have a feeling, from the answers here, that the exception is representative of a larger problem, processor or memory related.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see that kind of code in the SSCLI20 source code.  Which looks like this with all the noise removed:

```
FCIMPL3(void, SystemNative::ArrayClear, ArrayBase* pArrayUNSAFE, INT32 iIndex, INT32 iLength)
{
    BASEARRAYREF pArray = (BASEARRAYREF)pArrayUNSAFE;
    // error checks
    //.. 
    char* array = (char*)pArray->GetDataPtr();
    int size = pArray->GetMethodTable()->GetComponentSize();
    ZeroMemory(array + (iIndex - lb) * size, iLength * size);
}
```

In other words, it simply blasts 0 bytes into the elements.  The only way to get an SEHException is through a processor fault.  GC heap corruption.  Review any pinvoke or COM interop code.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for... I can't really post code to repro this, as the code is embedded in a fairly large application.  But all that is actually happening is that I am trying to clear a byte array of 4096 bytes.  The problem is that the error is cropping up inconsistently, so there really is no way to write a test-app for it.

Comment: Also, I don't have any pinvoke or COM interop code in my project, so it's looking more like some kind of corruption at a lower level than I have control over.

Comment: Painful.  Don't consider the CLR unless you have an old unpatched version.  Something environmental, crap that injects itself in any process.  What is the exception's ErrorCode value?

Comment: That's part of the problem... there is no ErrorCode value.  At least not one that I can trap.  My application crashes right after the exception, without exception :-p  I'm working on debugging this further, but it is looking more and more like the system that I am running it on is having problems.

Answer (score 6):

It's easiest to *envision* `Array.Clear` being written like so

```
public static void Array.Clear<T>(T[] array) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    array[i] = default(T);
  }
}
```

I realize Array.Clear is not actually a generic method, i'm trying to demonstrate a close mapping of what's going on under the hood.  Really though it's closer to

```
memcopy(&array, 0, array.Length * sizeof(T));
```

If this code is throwing an `SEHException` then the most likely cause is the memory around the source array is corrupted.  The most likely source is an incorrect PInvoke or COM interop call.