# Empty elements in C# byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

Is there any method to empty an *Byte array* in **C#**?

```
Byte[] array = new Byte[64]; // contain all 0

// write some value into the array

// need empty array with all 0's
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```
Byte[] array = new Byte[64];

Array.Clear(array, 0, array.Length);
```

Comment: It won't be optimized out of the `Release` build though, right? Eg: `SecureZeroMemory` vs `ZeroMemory` in Win32.

Comment: @c00000fd Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5557735/10399490)

Comment: What is the performance difference between the two methods? When would I use one over the other?

Answer (score 23):

Kindly use Array.Empty method

> byte[] rawBytes =  Array.Empty();

Comment: byte[] rawBytes = Array.Empty<byte>();

Comment: @sbr This has been helpful since I needed to pass it to a method in tests. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

I tried endlessly to use Array.Clear() to clear a large byte[] that I have in my program. It would NEVER work. I do not know why. But I found a solution:

> array = new byte[0];

Answer (score 3):

Use the "clear" method on Array.

```
 Array.Clear(array , 0, array.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    array[i] = 0;
```