# Parallel.For partitioning

Tags: c#, .net, performance, task-parallel-library

How is partitioning done for something like

```
Parallel.For(0, buffer.Length, (i)=> buffer[i] = 0);
```

My assumption was that for an `n` core machine, work would be partitioned `n way` and `n threads` will carry out the work payload. Which means for example `buffer.Length = 100 and n = 4, each thread will get 0-24, 25-49, 50-74, 75-99` blocks. (100 element array is an example to illustrate partitioning, but please consider an array of millions of items.)

Is this a fair assumption? Please discuss.

I noticed that `Array.Clear(...)` would perform much faster in this specific scenario. How do you rationalize this?

Comment: A 100-element integer array is so small that it fits on a core's cache. Besides, with an operation like "Clear" you are using memory I/O, not CPU cycles

Comment: The cost of creating and managing threads is relatively high. So it's only an advantage if each thread has a rather long running task. Just setting an integer variable to 0 is "nothing" compared to creating a thread. So in this scenario, the costs of having several threads far outweight the cost of one single thread doing all the work.

Comment: @Corak - Parallel uses pool threads so most of your comment does not apply.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 100 element array was an example to illustrate the partitioning. Don't base your answer on that. CPU has to set the memory value and it incurs cycles.

Comment: The answer is the same unles you use a VERY large number. Zeroing memory is extremely fast, has NO CPU overhead thus doesn't benefit from task-based parallelization at all

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Threads still need to be managed. If I'm wrong, I'm very interested in another explanation. Btw, I tested it with 100000000 items on a four core machine and `Array.Clear` is more than three times faster than `Parallel.For`.

Comment: Of course Clear() is faster, it can probably do a `memset` . Wrong testcase.

Comment: And I also tried `for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) { arr[i] = 0; }` which is also much slower than `Array.Clear`, but still faster than `Parallel.For`.

Comment: And here you see the overhead of synchronization ... You are using the worst possible example, where the benefit from parallelization is 0

Comment: The assumption that the `Parralel` class will limit itself to the number of threads you have on your machine is incorrect. If you want that behavior you need to pass in [ParallelOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.aspx) and set [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) to `Environment.ProcessorCount`. If you don't set it it will keep giving out as many threads as the TaskScheduler will allow.

Comment: Well, it *starts* from ProcessorCount, while the number of potential threads is far larger. MaxDOP is useful ONLY when you want to use more than ProcessorCount threads

Comment: Which by the way the [default value for it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.maximumconcurrencylevel.aspx) is `Int32.MaxValue`.

Comment: That's the default for the TaskScheduler, not ParallelOptions. Besides, that's the MAX not the one it starts with.

Comment: @Panagiotis the default value of [`ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) is -1, which means "unbounded". I am currently reading an [interesting github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1946 "Async parallel foreach"), where this fact is relevant.

Comment: @Panagiotis please take a look at [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wgFw95) fiddle. 100 pieces of work are processed instantly. The default behavior of the `Parallel` class, which is rather unfortunate IMHO, is to saturate the `ThreadPool`. The library with the behavior you describe ("use all available cores"), is PLINQ.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias that's an API proposal, not an issue. How is this related with this 8 year old question? And no, `Parallel` will use all available cores. It may *increase* the cores dynamically if needed. If you block every iteration, it will keep creating more threads. If you write bad-enough code you can make it saturate the thread pool. PLINQ makes it harder to write such bad code

Comment: @Panagiotis ha ha! I didn't notice that the discussion was so old. I though that it was a present day discussion. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias the TPL and related classes work hard to guide developers to correct patterns for each scenario. They can't prevent developers from using them improperly though. Asking why a library or method misbehaves if it's used improperly may be interesting for a chat but won't fix the original problem. I bet that if you use a blocking operation in PLINQ, eg in the `Select` clause, with an infinite iterator as a source, you'll be able to cause problems as well

Comment: @Panagiotis if you replace the `Thread.Sleep(1000)` in the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oNSBSH) with `for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { }`, the behavior is the same. The `ThreadPool` is saturated. It's not a matter of good vs bad user code.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias and if I use a hammer to drive a screw into a wall, I'll ruin the wall. We can find ways to break every class in the TPL. How is this related to this question? If anything, it shows that one should understand what each class is for before trying to "improve" things.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias and yes, newer classes implement higher-level patterns and fix problems with older ones. PLINQ is a higher-level abstraction, so it makes it harder to write bad code. Dataflow, which was introduced in 2012 solves the throttling problem caused by starting 1000 tasks and trying to throttle them afterwards. Channels solve the async problems of BlockingCollection

Comment: My comments are not related to the question (I've not even read it yet). I am responding to your comments where you assume that the `Parallel` class limits itself to the number of the available processors (at least initially). I hope that the fiddle example shows definitely that this is not true. The limiting factor for the `Parallel` class is the `ThreadPool`. Btw the `Parallel` is by no means obsolete. It just have a bad default (IMHO). If you specify the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

First for the easy part. A 100-element array is so small that it can easily fit in a core's cache. Besides, clearing the array is equivalent to setting a memory area to 0s, something that is available as a CPU command and therefore as fast as you can make it.

In fact, SSE commands and parallel-optimized memory controllers mean that the chipset can probalbly clear memory in parallel using only a single CPU command.

On the other hand, Parallel.For introduces some overhead. It has to partition the data, create the appropriate tasks to work on them, collect the results and return the final result. Below Parallel.For, the runtime has to copy the data to each core, handle memory synchronization, collect the results etc. In your example, this can be significantly larger that the actual time needed to zero the memory locations.

*In fact, for small sizes it is quite possible that 99.999% of the overhead is memory synchronization as each core tries to access **the same memory page**. Remember, memory locking is at the page level and you can fit 2K 16-bit ints in a 4K memory page.*

As for how PLINQ schedules tasks - there are many different partitioning schemes used, depending on the operators you use. Check [Partitioning in LINQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/partitioning-in-plinq/) for a nice intro. In any case, the partitioner will try to determine whether there is any benefit to be gained from partitioning and may not partition the data at all.

In your case, the partitioner will probably use Ranged partitioning. Your payload uses only a few CPU cycles so all you see is the overhead of partitioning, creating tasks, managing synchronization and collecting the results.

A better benchmark would be to run some aggregations on a large array, eg. counts and averages and the like.

Comment: +1 for the link and memory synchronization point. CPU instruction to clear memory - is that speculation or can you back that one up?

Comment: Clear uses the OS ZeroMemory function. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557609/what-does-array-clear-actually-do-under-the-covers for starters. As for CPU instructions, setting a memory range to a single value is one of the simplest  SIMD instructions

Comment: SIMD instructions have specific data width. They can't set arbitrary range of memory to a value AFAIK. So in that case memory still has to be read, value set and written back in a loop. But of course this would be much faster than setting each element one at a time.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the CLR doesn't use SIMD instructions.

Comment: Didn't say it does. Said Array.Clear uses (Rtl)ZeroMemory which lives in driver land. SIMD was at least one example of commands that can clear memory. This Q has become *MUCH* too broad.

Comment: the link to "Partitioning in LINQ" is broken. I believe the updated link is [Partitioning in PLINQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/partitioning-in-plinq/)

Answer (score 4):

The optimisation of PFX/PLINQ is complex. However, here is the basic picture...

**Input-Side Optimisation:**

PLINQ has three partitioning strategies for assigning input elements to threads:

<kbd>**Strategy**</kbd>                    <kbd>**Element allocation**</kbd><kbd>**Relative performance**</kbd>
<kbd>Chunk partitioning</kbd>         <kbd>Dynamic</kbd>                <kbd>Average</kbd>      
<kbd>Range partitioning</kbd>         <kbd>Static</kbd>                    <kbd>Poor to excellent</kbd>      
<kbd>Hash partitioning</kbd>           <kbd>Static</kbd>                    <kbd>Poor</kbd>

For query operators that require comparing elements (`GroupBy`, `Join`, `GroupJoin` etc.) PLINQ always chooses hash partitioning which is relatively inefficient because it must pre-calculate the hash code of every element (so that elements with identical codes can be run on the same thread).

For all other query operators you can choose either range or chunk partitioning. By default, if the input sequence is indexable (if it is and array of inherits from `IList<T>`) PLINQ will choose range partitioning; otherwise it will choose chunk partitioning.

range partitioning is faster with long sequences for which every element takes a similar amount of CPU time. Otherwise, chunk partitioning is faster.

**How they work:**

Chunk partitioning works by having each worker thread periodically grab small 'chunks' of elements from the input sequence to process. PLINQ starts by allocating very small chunks and then increases this amount as the query progresses; this ensures that small sequences are effectively parallelized and large sequences don't case excessive 'round-tripping'. If a worker thread happens to finish it job quickly it will end up getting more chunks. This system keeps every thread equally busy and the machine's core 'balanced'. The downside of this method is that fetching elements from a shared input sequence requires locking and this can add overhead.

Range partitioning bypasses the normal input-side enumeration and pre-allocates an equal number of element to each worker thread avoiding contention on the input sequence. If a thread finishes early using this method it will sit idle until the other threads have finished.

**Parralell `For` and `Foreach`:**

By default, for `For`/`Foreach` loops PLINQ will use range partitioning.

I hope this helps.

Comment: “By default, for For/Foreach loops PLINQ will use range partitioning.” I think that's an oversimplification. If you use `ForEach()` on an `IEnumerable<T>`, range partitioning can't be used, because the length is not known up front. In that case, chunk partitioning is used instead.